# How do I undo or fix a bad batch file rename for stripping characters

Tags: command-line, regex, rename, filename

I used the following command to attempt to remove special characters and replace them with a "." how can I undo this action?

```
find . -type f -exec rename 's/[^A-Za-z0-9._]/./g' {} +
```

I have used Ubuntu for over 10 years, but don't have much regex experience, I should have tested the above command on unimportant files first, DOH!

When I browse the folder from a windows machine, it flashes a bunch of hidden files for a second,
 so I assume they are all still there, just with some odd naming that prevents them from being accessed.

Obviously the command had a syntax error, or that I should have used a "_" instead of a "."

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not possible to undo the action. Try to get a pattern/view in the current names, and then we can help with renaming these to your desired form (now).

Comment: when I do from the command line "ls -l" it does not show the files any longer, when browsing the share from windows it shows the files for a split second and they all start with two ".."

would it be possible to rename the first two characters of all files to _ I think maybe that would unhide them.

Comment: yes all files now start with ".." also they are now all in the root directory instead of their respective sub folders.

Comment: would this work? rename 's/^/1_/' *

Comment: Please [edit] your question, add some sample filenames (be sure that these represent all the possible formats), and your desired filenames from them.

Comment: There is about 12,000 files with varying formats, my original goal was just to remove non alpha numberic characters, I believe I have figured it out though, it seems the command did do what I want, except that all files were appended with ".." to the beginning of them I have managed to remove the first two characters from all filenames, and this has fixed the issue, now I just have to get them sorted back into their proper folders

Comment: upon further inspection EVERY file was appended with "..folder.folder." to the file name. I now have access to all the files, but it looks like I have a TON of file renaming to do

Comment: Since ``find` prepends the starting point to its results, `find . -type f` would have resulted in a listing like `./dir/file`, then your `-exec rename` would have replaced all the path separators as periods resulting in `..dir.file` and so on

Comment: yep, thats what it did, gonna take while to put all the files back into their folders and rename them now, i may experiment with trying to write a script to do it.